# What is the significance of fast motion effect in some scenes?

Tags: plot-explanation, 20th-century-women

In *20th Century Woman*, What is the significance of fast motion effect in some scenes?

I mean people move really fast; In technical term "Fast Motion".

Comment: Well, I am just wondering how you manage these multiple accounts.